# Proper way to use a promise to build array of object then send to client - nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm attempting to build an array of objects and send it to client. The issue is the the array being sent is blank, because of asynchronous code (or so I'm learning).

I would like the loop to build the array, then send response from server to client. I am told a promise is the best way to do this here, but I am unable to understand how to implement. How would a promise look here?

```js
var rates = [];
for (var i = 0, len = cryptoxArray.length; i < len; i++) {

  cryptoxArray[i].getRate({
    pair: "XBT_USD"
  }, function(err, rateResponse) {
    if (!err)
      rates.push(rateResponse);
  });

  //I want this last part to wait until the array has been built so 
  //the array is '[object][object]'

  console.log('rates: ' + rates); // now is outputting 'rates: []'
  return res.json(rates);
```

Comment: you could add a secondary counter and fire the console.log only when the counter reaches a certain index, in your case that would be counter = i because you would be at the end of the array

Comment: What's `cryptoxArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you specified promises

```
Promise.all(cryptoxArray.map(function (cryptox) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return cryptox.getRate({ pair: "XBT_USD" }, function (err, rateResponse) {
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rateResponse);
    });
  });
})).then(function (rates) {
  return res.json(rates);
});
```

or in ultra ES2015

```
Promise.all(cryptoxArray.map(cryptox =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        cryptox.getRate({ pair: "XBT_USD" }, (err, rateResponse) => 
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(rateResponse)
        )
    )
))
.then(rates=> res.json(rates));
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, just checked that again. Never mind.

Comment: so, where is the user pushing the values to the rates array?

Comment: @mnemosdev The Array#map call does that.

Comment: oops, typo on my part - I used results instead of rates, let me fix ... the rates (was results) in `Promise.all(....).then(rates` is an array of rates as per the question